# Matlab Convertion of HSV type in Matlab

Tags: matlab, types, hsv

I'm looking for making image corrections in a movie using matlab.
I've googling for examples to splitting the movie into images, and then another example to improve image's quality.
As I'm using several examples, I got into a issue and I was wondering if it is possible to convert an HSV image into a uint8 type?

Comment: what type is your HSV image? What is the data range?

Comment: HSV is a color space and uint8 is a data type. do you mean that you want to convert HSV in to gray scale? if so you can take the V channel of your image, it is the gray scale image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HSV image is of type double and the range lies between 0 and 1 then you might have luck by multiplying it by 256 and casting to uint8:

```
HSVuint8 = uint8(HSV.*256);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any HSV image into RGB using [hsv2rgb](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/hsv2rgb.html)

Once converted you